# How can we use '=' operator to assign value to our custom made datatype in c++?

Tags: c++, string

I have created a basic string class and i want to assign it some value
but the problem is that I have to do something like this...
`string str("Hello");`
Isn't there a way so i can do it something like....
`string str = "Hello";`
Like how c++ std:: defined types (vector,string etc) do?

And also I want that instead of typing `std::cout << str.val()` I can do `std::cout << str;` to access its value and same for modifying (or updating) it.

```
#include<iostream>
class string
{
  private:
  char* str; // An uninitialized string
  public:
  string(char* text) // Constructor which takes a string
  {
    str = text;
  }
  char* val() // used to access the value stored in String
  {
   return str;
  }
  void update(char* string2) // used to update the value of string
  {
    str = string2;
  }
};

int main()
{
  string myStr("Hello World\n"); //initializes a string object
  std::clog << myStr.val();

  myStr.update("Bye World\n"); //updates the value of myStr
  std::clog << myStr.val();
}
```

Thanks to whoever answers....

Comment: `"Hello"` is a `char const[6]` and will pointer decay into `char const*`, not `char*`.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this using overloaded operators

`string& operator= ( const string & );`

`string& operator= ( const char *);`

Answer (score -1):

You need to implement these operators ('=' and '<<') manually. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators (or search for `c++ operator overloading` in case of broken links)

In this case, you can add this code to your `string` class.

```cpp
// Allow assignment with another `string`
string& operator=(const string& other) {
  str = other.str;
  return *this;
}

// This is optional. Without this, the previous `operator=` will be called
// with `other` implicitly converted to a `string`
string& operator=(char* other) {
  str = other;
  return *this;
}

// With the `friend` keyword, you can write a global function inside a class
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const string& obj)
{
    return os << obj.str;
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/30681581)

Comment: @theVoogie Thanks for reminding. I have edited the answer and I will pay more attention in the future.

Answer (score -1):

You can Overload the operators = and << like Below

1. **Overloading the = Operator**

   ```
   string& operator = (char * text)
   {
      this->str=text;
      return *this;
   }
   ```
2. **Overloading the << Operator**

   ```
   friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& outputstream,string& thestr)
   {
       outputstream<<thestr.val();
       return outputstream;
   }
   ```

**So the Overall will be like below**

```
#include<iostream>
class string
{
  private:
  char* str; // An uninitialized string
  public:
  string(char* text) // Constructor which takes a string
  {
    str = text;
  }
  char* val() // used to access the value stored in String
  {
   return str;
  }
  void update(char* string2) // used to update the value of string
  {
    str = string2;
  }

  string& operator = (char * text)
  {
    this->str=text;
    return *this;
  }

  friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& outputstream,string& thestr)
  {
    outputstream<<thestr.val();
    return outputstream;
  }

};

int main()
{
  string myStr="Hello World\n"; //initializes a string object
  std::clog<<myStr;

  myStr="Bye World\n"; //updates the value of myStr
  std::clog << myStr;
}
```